# Is it possible to set a currency for a custom field (Money)

Tags: custom-fields

I'm writing CRM extensions allowing to see clculated summary of transactions for each contact.

Each currency has it's own custom group with set of custom fields.
One of custom fields id total_contributions (data_type:Money) but problem starts when contact have contributions in other currency than default.

Ex.
Two tabs: Summary PLN, Summary USD, each has it's on custom group and fields set.
Example contact made 200$ donation in USD, but default currency is PLN, in custom contact tab, with USD curency, there will be displayed "200 zł" wich is wrong, it should be 200$ but it will display bvalue in system default currency, because custom field has no option to set currency.

I've checked hook `hook_civicrm_alterCustomFieldDisplayValue`  but it won't allow to change currency of displayed field.

Any advice ?

Comment: side comment about your goal of a "calculated summary" - are you aware of these https://civicrm.org/extensions/summary-fields, https://civicrm.org/extensions/joinerys-more-summary-fields and https://civicrm.org/extensions/synopsis just in case any of these

Comment: @petednz-fuzion yes, we know them but we neded somethin way more faster :-)

Comment: I agree it would be useful to be able to set currency per field. I don't think it's currently possible.